# Finding the exact occurrence of Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
Products::whereIn('category_id', ['223', '15', '20'])
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

How can I fix this example so that it finds the exact occurrence of `category_id = 223` and `15` and `20` and also necessarily `active = 1`?

Comment: Exact occurrence as how? Your question is not quite clear. Doesn't your code do that already?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to look for exactly `category_id = 15, 20 and 223`, it can only be one...

But, if you still want that, your query is nearly there, you can do:

```php
Products::where('category_id', '223')
    ->where('category_id', '15')
    ->where('category_id', '20')
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

But, again, that should return an empty `Collection`. `whereIn` is a simple `IN` in SQL, that means it is an `OR` for all the values you want.

Comment: the array category_id is not initially known
in my example, 15(active) = 1, 20(active)  - 0 and 223(active)  = 1 and at the same time, the result is still returned

Answer (score -1):

Use from this group. Because, maybe you use `OR` condition in future.  Therefore, your condition will not work correctly.
For example

```php
    Products::query()->where(function ($query){
        $query->where('category_id', '223')
            ->where('category_id', '15')
            ->where('category_id', '20');
    })->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

Explain of query above will work like that:

```sql
Select * from products where (category_id = 223 and category_id = 15 and category_id = 20) and active = 1
```